# R cannot be resolved to a variable error when setting background

Tags: android, background, r.java-file

I am making an app in which I set an image as the background but when I set this image as the  background the R.java file disappears and I get the "`R cannot be resolve to a variable error`"

**EDIT**:None of the usual "`R cannot be resolved to a variable`" solutions did not work

Any solutions?

Comment: what is the name of your image?

Comment: the problem was in the name of the image it had the invalid charecter '-'

Comment: I cant accept the answer before 10mins of posting it

Comment: I am new here...can I know why I got a down vote?

Comment: because your question is so basic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem mostly appear due to due to build path errors, to check problems see Eclipse Menu-> Windows -? Show View-> Error Logs and Eclipse Menu-> Windows -? Show View->Problems. and According the problem listed resolve the error, and then try to compile the project.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work. I'm not sure.

```
1. Change the name of the image(in drawable directory) you are trying to use.
2. Clean the project
```

Also, check your imports if u are importing android.R class instead of your own R.java class

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing android.R instead of your own R class?

`Try clean the project` or do a manual import.